# Which linux command can I check the full size of the VM?

Tags: linux

In which command can I check how big is my entire VM? I want to extend one of my disk with extra +40GB, but I'm not sure is there enough space? I need a linux command, thanks.

Comment: `lsblk` or `df -h`

Comment: df which stands for "disk free"  shows available memory space: try df -ah

Comment: lsblk, in which line can you see, whether you have extra 40 size in your virtual machine or not, or with df -h.

Comment: If you are using logical volumes, commands like pvdisplay, vgdisplay and lvdisplay will also be useful.

Comment: `lsblk | grep disk`